# Robust import of Python package modules in nested git submodule structure

Tags: python, git, import, nested, git-submodules

This might be a duplicate, but I didn't really find questions with this problem (nor a helpful answer).

The setup is as follows (simplified):

I have three different git Python projects using each other as submodules (note: I use the name `submodule` here referring to the git submodules. In Python, they are not modules, but packages, as pointed out in the answers):

- main_project
- submodule_1 (used by main_project)
- submodule_2 (used by submodule_1)

So the tree for the main project looks like:

```
- main_project
+- submodule_1
++- submodule_2
```

The Python code for importing submodule_2 in submodule_1 is like:

```
from submodule_2 import *
```

The Python code for importing submodule_1 in the main_project is like:

```
from submodule_1 import *
```

Now, when I run the main project, I get an error for the import of submodule_2 in submodule_1, as the paths are different from the main_project perspective.

To fix that, one could change the import in submodule_1 to:

```
from submodule_1.submodule_2 import *
```

That way, however, the import only works from running within the main_project and not when running submodule_1 independently.

I also experimented with changing the directories within the Python scripts, but that didn't really help, either.

And adding the packages (submodules) to the path is also not really an option (as it removes flexibility and easy portability).

Answer (score 0):

Python import paths are always relative to the directory where the interpreter is run. As you pointed out, this works in `submodule_1` when running the main project:

```
from submodule_1.submodule_2 import *
```

but it will also work when running `submodule_1` independently if you run the interpreter from where the main project is so that `submodule_1.submodule_2` can refer to a valid relative path:

```
main_project> python submodule_1/__init__.py
```

Note that `submodule_1` is a misnomer since a directory containing Python modules should really be called a package rather than a module.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my bad nomenclature! I'll fix that.

Comment: Regarding your answer: Of course this will work when I execute `submodule_1` from within the main project. The problem is that `submodule_1` is developed (and tested) independently and used in several projects (so the structure is not always the same). Thus my question here.